# Attempting to create automatic wallpaper, but background either goes black or module error

Tags: python, automation, scheduled-tasks

```
import datetime, time, ctypes
import schedule

def wallpaperSet():
    file = ''
    time=datetime.datetime.now().hour
    if 0 <= time <= 10:
        file = "D:\\Games\\Sys files\\Firewatch Mod Day.png"
        ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, file, 0)
        ...

schedule.every(2).hour.do(wallpaperSet())
start_time = time.process_time()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.process_time() - start_time))

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(100)
```

error is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schedule'

However, schedule works with pip/pip3 install, and so I have no idea why this isn't working. Are there workarounds, or can I use an alternative. So far, before finding schedule, I looked at using time(), but these all seemed incredibly bulky, and as a beginner this put me off.

Comment: Did pip/pip3 install return an error? If so, what version of python/pip are you using?

Comment: Can you verify whether your python shell and pip/pip3 point to same directory?

Comment: How do verify that.